# return type of printf() in c

Tags: c, printf, output, return-type

What would be the output of the following C program? (Is it a valid C program?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=43;
    printf("%d\n",printf("%d",printf("%d",i)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not [just try it yourself](http://ideone.com/)?

Comment: [Click me](http://ideone.com/JuODfz).

Comment: `printf` returns the actual character count. Now check your self

Comment: You might want to start by reading a [`printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: try searching stackoverflow next time

Comment: output : `4321` , it's valid C program.

Comment: Output `"43"` from inner `printf()`, which returns 2 as 2 characters where printed. so `"2"` is printed next.  The middle `printf()` then returns 1 as one character was printed.  The outside `printf()` then prints `"1\n"` and returns 2.  This final return value of 2 is not used.  Total output `"4321\n"`.

Comment: ya got it ,thank you chux :)

Answer (score 1):

printf On success, the total number of characters written is returned
then console is :

4321

;)

Comment: how is the last character 1 ?

Comment: @beginner: 1 is the return value of the previous `printf` which printed `2` (a single character).

Comment: i run it as follows for my convenience , but my doubt is , from inner printf() we get 432 and its length should be 3 ryt?                        #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i=43;
        printf("%d",printf("%d",printf("%d",i)));    //4321
        printf("\n");
        
        printf("%d",i);                              //43
        printf("\n");
        
        
        printf("%d",printf("%d",i));                //432
        printf("\n");
        
         printf("%d",printf("%d",printf("%d",i)));      //4321 
       
   
       return 0;
}

Comment: command calculated from last printf and should be '43' then its length '2' and finall '1' means length of '2' then the answer will be 4321 or 43, 2& 1

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the documentation of `printf` eg [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) :

> Return value

```
   Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
   characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
   strings).
```